# Relations between Function Variables in Computations

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, functions, variable-definitions, argument-patterns

I have the relation λ=c/f, respectively f=c/λ and a simple function n[λ_]:=λ²+1. I'd like to differentiate the function with respect to f, then plot it as a function of λ again. For this, I can define the function

```
n[λ_]:=λ²+1
```

I can now compute

```
D[n[c/f], f]
```

To get that as a function of λ, I tried

```
nplot[f_]:=D[n[c/f], f]
```

(which does not work) and then

```
Plot[nplot[c/f],{f,a,b}]
```

Is there no elegant way to switch between λ and f in plotting and computing - such, that I could just say

```
derivative[f]=D[n[f],f]
Plot[derivative[λ],{λ,0,10}]
```

…?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an [`UpValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UpValues) for `λ` to encapsulate your known relation:

```
SetAttributes[c, Constant]
Dt[f == c/λ, f]
```

> 1 == -c Dt[λ, f]/λ^2

Hence, we can define:

```
λ /: Dt[λ, f] = -λ^2/c
```

> -λ^2/c

Then:

```
n[λ_] := λ^2+1

Dt[n[λ], f]
```

> -2 λ^3/c

which is the requested derivative of `n[λ]` with respect to `f` in terms of `λ`.

Comment: Ah, that's neat. How would I then quickly plot n[λ] and Dt[n[λ],f]] as a function of f? For the first, I could just use Plot[n[c/λ],{λ,a,b}], but then I again have to give the range in terms of λ, not f.